# I can't see smoke in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

[image: blender 3.6 cycles smoke with principled volume node]

i don't get it maybe i'm just stupid because in the tutorials it just works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smoke simulations in blender themself have no visible geometry, they simply define where a volume exists based off of various factors.  To properly visualize this, you must define a shader for the volume input of the material, not the surface as you have done.  The reason nothing is visible at all is because the boundary geometry you have defined is shown as a bounding box, and therefore there is no surface for the shader to be applied to.

Comment: thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).